# How to search for an exact match in solr using pysolr function "solr.search"

Tags: solr, pysolr

I am using pysolr 3.1.0 to interface queries with the solr server.
I am able to get the list of the search term entered. But I am not able to find an exact match.

I am using the below command

> results = solr.search(packagename, rows=5000)

Any idea what changes I have to do in the query for exact match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the query was that I had not mentioned the field or id in which the search was to be executed.

The query should be something like this

> results = solr.search(' id:"searchstring" ')

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes

`results = solr.search('package name', rows=50)`

Add double quotes to query keyword to work for exact match

`results = solr.search('"package name"', rows=50)`

Comment: In python console check wt it returns for len(results) `print len(results)
` and crosscheck in solr admin for q="package name" how many results you getting

Comment: Yes, i have verified my result , it works if i run a query with normal curl command and set indent=true. But solr.search option is not working

Comment: does it returns any error for this statement `results = solr.search(packagename, rows=5000)`

Comment: No, it does not return any error. But I don't get exact match in the results.